# Get stock data problems

Tags: python, pandas

I was making getting stock data file and output was just

```
In Progress
[]
```

what's the matter?

```
 import quandl
 from datetime import datetime as dt

    def get_stock_data(stock_ticker):
        print("In Progress")

        start_date = dt(2019, 1, 1)
        end_date = dt.now()

        quandl_api_key = "tJDGptkdfqwjYi123RVV"
        quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = quandl_api_key

        source = "WIKI/" + stock_ticker

        data = quandl.get(source, start_date=str(start_date), end_date=str(end_date))
        data = data[["Open", "High", "Low", "Volume", "Close"]].values

        print(data)

        return data
 get_stock_data("AAPL")
```

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
There are plenty of places where you should be tracing the data you fetched, to help determine where the problem lies.  Insert a few useful `print` commands and include the output; this example should be less than half its present size, with a known point of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. However recent stock data is a Premium product from Quandl and I presume you are just on the free subscription, hence your dataframe comes back empty. If you change the dates to 2017, you will get some results but that's as far as it goes on the free subscription it seems.